# The possibility of can and may

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, can-may

I ask about the possibility of *can*.
I would like to ask further to the past Stack Exchange answer.

Question

[What is the difference between 'can', 'could', 'may' and 'might'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/99957/what-is-the-difference-between-can-could-may-and-might)

The following sentence is part of the answer to the question.

> Furthermore, modern English, the semantics of can stretches to cover that of may (but only in the area of permission, rather than possibility).

I respect this answer. then, modern English, why didn't the semantics of *can* stretch to cover that of *may* in the area of possibility?

A:  It may be that the bird escaped from the cage last night.

B: * It can be that the bird escaped from the cage last night.

(This example sentence is taken from Sawada Harumi(1991: 208).)

Comment: But it _can_. Maybe. Right? :)

Comment: *It **can** get cold at night where I live.* That's a distinct *possibility*, whether or not I give *permission* (same as *It **may** get cold*). I think perhaps the distinction you're making only arises when ***it may be*** is connected to a ***that-*** clause.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question, and the question quoted in this question, is the same, really.

Put as an aphorism, it's simple enough:

- **Every Modal Auxiliary Verb In English Is Unique**.

Every one of the 9 auxiliary verbs has some partial resemblance and partial parallelism to other modals -- but none of them are completely parallel, all participate in different idioms, all have different meanings when combined with negations and quantifications, none of them are paradigmatic in any useful way. Each one is unique, in other words.

Modal auxiliary verbs are basically on the road to becoming new inflections, the way the verb forms of Latin *habere* became the paradigmatic person markers of Romance future tenses. They've been stripped of all their inflections (except the -d/-t in the 5 modals formed from preterite roots, which adds a syllable in negative contractions), so their paradigms are no longer available (*thou mayst* or *thou mayeth*?), and their monosyllabic structure slips through the contractions to show up as a consonant here and a nasalization there in ordinary speech.

*Can* is a good example of just how weird (another word for *unique*, really) modal auxiliaries can be. First, there are several categories for modals.

- A modal auxiliary is either a `Necessary` modal, like *must*, or a `Possible` modal, like *may*. Necessary modals include *must, shall, will, should, would*, and Possible modals include *can, could, may, might*. Necessary is also called "Square" and "Possible" is also called "Diamond", because of the logical symbols used for them. Every language has both types of modal, though they aren't always auxiliary verbs as in English.
- A modal auxiliary verb can contract, and usually does, with other auxiliary verbs, negative morphemes, prepositions, complementizers, and other components of the verb phrase. This can get quite complicated. In some American dialects, affirmative *can* is pronounced with a higher lax vowel /kɛn/, instead of /kæn/. The negative *can't*, however, is pronounced /kæn/, with the final /t/ suppressed. Or the /kn/ sequence (especially with a syllabic /n/) might get used by itself:

  - /ˌknɛnibəɾi'siyəm/ *Can anybody see him?*
- Every modal auxiliary has at least two senses, with various names, of which the two most common are the Deontic, or "Social" sense, like the deontic *must* of

  - *Cinderella must be home by midnight.*
    Deontic senses have to do with authority, permission, obligation, and control of behavior. They often stem from social prohibitions and prejudices, rather than logic or planning.

  and the Epistemic, or "Logical" sense, like the epistemic *must* of

  - *Cinderella must have gone to the wrong party*
    Epistemic senses represent conclusions affirmed by the speaker, generally after consideration of circumstances, times, past behavior, and motives, of what seems to be most or least likely situation.

Note that *can* does not normally use an epistemic sense in the affirmative:

- **This can be the right place*

does not mean

- *This might be the right place*.

It means, if anything, that if enough work were done to transform it, that it could be made into the right place, rather than that there is a possibility we've arrived.

**Provided** it's in a negative environment, however, we **can** (deontic) use an epistemic *can*,  because epistemic *can* is a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299).

- *This can't be the right place.*

*Can* has another sense beside its epistemic and deontic senses, however; it has to do with personal ability. Indeed, *be able to* is the usual periphrastic equivalent of ability *can*

- *He can/is able to leap tall buildings at a single bound.*

This doesn't mean he just did it, or does it often, or in fact has ever been seen to do it -- just that he has the capacity, according to the speaker. This entails the possibility, of course, but it's a different sort of possibility.

And that's what one finds every time when investigating modals -- they're sui generis to a fault. Every single one has dozens of special functions and constructions and interpretations that are welded or glued or stapled or soldered into or onto or underneath some part of the Big Machine, and they all work. More or less. But there really aren't many useful generalizations except the one I put in boldface above.

Comment: Oh, one more weirdity of _can_ but no other modal: with sense verbs (_see, hear, feel, smell, taste_ and the verb idiom _speak (a language)_, use of _can_ is equivalent to simple present tense: _I **can** speak Spanish/hear the band/smell the peanuts_ == _I speak Spanish/hear the band/smell the peanuts_

Comment: This looks like a real goldmine! I'll probably end up revisiting it repeatedly over the coming days / weeks / years. But I'm intrigued by *on the road to becoming new inflections.* I have the impression English is very different to, say, Latin, largely because English has "evolved" to use word order and "function" words to do the job of Latin inflections. But if modals can turn into inflections, that feels like something different is going on. Compared to other languages today, does English make significantly more (or less) use of modal verbs?

Comment: Modals are all over the place. Every time I started investigating something, there'd be weird modal constructions to cope with. Essentially, they've been released from their verbal duties and are seeping in here and there wherever they can be made to fit in. It'll be a while before they settle down.

Comment: I think politicians *love* modals, because they make it so much easier to says things in a way that requires active engagement from the audience to "choose" the intended meaning. Trump is often accused of not having great command of English, but I think he's a past master at writing tweets that his supporters interpret favourably, but which enrage his detractors (he's not interested in *communicating* with his political enemies; he just likes winding them up! :)

Comment: +1 for your thoroughness. You are quite learned. Are you claiming that 'He can still be alive' is not a counterexample to the claim that negative polarity obtains to *epistemic 'can'*? The property of aliveness is not a capacity or ability, but an essential property. I'll reread to see if I misstepped.

Comment: I've reread and reflected, and I see no issue with 'This can be the right place'. It simply expresses more confidence than 'This might be the right place'. If I were shopping for a home with my wife and I were to say 'This can be the home for the rest of our life', I'd be communicating that I'm strongly open to the possibility of purchasing it as a "foverever home". In fact, my wife can simply push back saying 'This *might* be the home for the rest of our life', and the implicature would be clear. We're still looking. (I offer as an example because this happened.)

Answer (score 2):

*Can* **does** stretch to cover the "possibility" sense of  *may,* but it uses *could.*

> It could be that the bird escaped last night.

It's part of a conditional construction, which I'm going to leave to others' answers to flesh out.

Answer (score 0):

> A: It may be that the bird escaped from the cage last night.
> B: * It can be that the bird escaped from the cage last night.

**Can absolutely expresses possibility. There's nothing wrong with B, but it does have a slightly different meaning.** [Merriam-Webster's definition of 'can'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can) is evidence that can is used for possibility. In fact, the example is **modal**-**adverb**-**copula**:

> c
> —used to indicate possibility
> Do you think he can still be alive? Those things can happen.

Anyone who tells you that can can't be used to describe possibility is completely ignorant of [modal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) and the [basics of modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modality_(linguistics)). The real question is what sort of possibility is expressed? 'Can' expresses **factual possibility** and one of its [subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) cousins 'could' expresses **hypothetical possibility**. The difference between 'can' and subjunctives is one of what philosophers of language call [propositional attitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_attitude). One can view the difference between factuals versus hypotheticals and counterfactuals as expressing a degree of confidence in belief. So, your two sentences might be translated for clarity:

> A: It may be that the bird *escaped* from the cage last night.

I'm not sure that the bird escaped from the cage last night. It might have happened.

> B: It can *be* that the bird escaped from the cage last night.

It is possible that the bird escaped last night. Birds escape cages.

*PS* On rereading my post, I've done the same thing as a [hedge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) in one of my final sentences:

> your two sentences might be translated for clarity

I could have written 'your two sentences *can* be translated for clarity', but I did not. Why? Because philosophically, translation is a sticky business with [issues of indeterminacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminacy_of_translation), and having many arguments about synonymy and translation, it was prudent of me to offer that my [reasoning is opening to defeat](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/). :D