# First conditional with "would" instead of "will"

Tags: conditionals

Consider the following sentence with a first conditional:

> > If it rains tomorrow, I will go to the cinema.

All the examples of first conditionals that I found use "will" instead of "would." Is it possible to replace "will" with "would" while retaining the same exact meaning, i.e.,

> > If it rains tomorrow, I would go to the cinema.

Or, would I have to put the inflected verb in preterite form (as mentioned in [this related posting](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/97794)), like this:

> > If it rained tomorrow, I would go to the cinema.

[Edit 1: I clarified that I want to retain the same meaning among these examples.]

[Edit 2: Corrected silly mistake where the first example was the same as the second example.]

Comment: *Will* implies it is absolutely going to happen.  *Would* implies it -might- happen.

Comment: No, the first one doesn't have the same meaning. RoDaSm's answer is correct: *"If it rains tomorrow, I would go to the cinema"* is conditional advice suggesting that the person you're talking to should go to the cinema in the case of rain.

Comment: [“It is clear that a division of conditionals into the zero, first, second, and third categories does not adequately reflect actual usage.”](http://clok.uclan.ac.uk/1531/1/elt.ccp101.full_1531.pdf) —from ***“If only it were true: the problem with the four conditionals”,*** Christian Jones and Daniel Waller, *ELT Journal* 65:1 pp 24–32 (2011), Oxford University Press,  doi: 10.1093/elt/ccp101.

Comment: @PeterShor, were you only talking about the sentence in the question, or do you consider all such sentences (i.e. with a would in place of will, and a present-tense verb in if-clause) as grammatically incorrect? // And, what do you think about *1.* "If you decide to sell the car, we would make an offer" and *2.* "If you ask me nicely, I would come with you"? Do you find both of them unacceptable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a mixed conditional, not a first conditional. Your sentence gives advice to another person, and is not a statement of you own personal purpose.

*If it rains, I will go tomorrow* is a statement of **what you would do** given the condition of *If it rains*.

If *it rains, I would go tomorrow* is **advice given to another person** as to their best actions given the condition *If it rains*. In spoken English it would be said as *If it rains, I'd go tomorrow*.

*If it rained, I would go tomorrow* is a conditional that suggest that you will perform an action that you do not think is likely to happen.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Peter Shor: excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the "would" case it means that my going tomorrow is psychologically remote. So the "would" part is loosely dependent on the first part. The hearer has to understand that even if it rains tomorrow, my going to cinema is not that certain.